# Any way to programmatically set BizTalk Message Context property?

Tags: biztalk

Is there any way to set `BTS.RetryCount` or `WCF.Action` not in a Message Assignment Shape?

I have a special orchestration for dynamic message sending, its parameters are `Message` and `ServiceName` and it has a dynamic port which is easily configured with UDDI service. The thing I can't do in that orchestrations is I can't set `WCF.Action` for a message, I should create a new one because it's prohibited in BizTalk to modify a message anywhere outside a Construct shape. So it's very inconvenient for me to set this property every time I want to send a message, I thought I would be able to do all the UDDI & routing stuff in a one dedicated orchestration which I later can just call with parameters.

Comment: Do you have the actionname in the document somewhere?  Like a custom header?

Comment: No, it is stored in UDDI

Comment: Sounds like a fun solution. Is it a service bus implementation for a client or customer?  Or are you just testing stuff out?

Comment: Why is it fun? We store all information about web services of connected systems in UDDI, that's what it is designed for, am I right?

Comment: I meant fun in a good way. As in interesting. No disrespect or critique intended mate. I just haven't seen many implementations where UDDI was used, so I thought it sounded interesting. And yeah - I think that was the intended purpose. Or at least one of them.

Comment: Well, you have to store configuration either in a db table or in config file, but as for me UDDI is quite appropriate solution because it lets your partners edit info about their services without asking me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not modify those properties in a pipeline component? You can then execute the pipeline inside the orchestration.

**UPDATE**

What I mean is you can create a pipeline component to set the context properties of the message as it passes through. Then you can create a pipeline which includes this component and execute it inside your orchestration by passing a message through it. This message will then have those context properties set.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood you correctly. "Can you not modify those properties in a pipeline component?"? I don't use any.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not create a new message in an assignment shape, of the same type as the message you need to modify

```
NewMessage = OldMessageWithTheDynamicPropertiesSet;
```

and copy over all the properties

```
NewMessage(*)* = OldMessageWithTheDynamicPropertiesSet(*);
```

and then set the properties you need to set. You can also set the WCF action that way.

```
NewMessage(WCF.Action)=....
NewMessage(BTS.REtryCount)= 666
```

And then you send this new message out.

Comment: Of course, yes, but that's what I want to avoid because I already have a new message dedicated to be sent. Copying the message is an overhead as I suspect

Comment: It Is an overhead, but how large is the message?  And how many do you plan to send per minute or hour or whatever? Memory is pretty cheap these days.